# Doctest for dynamically created objects

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, doctest, docstring

What is the best way to test code like this (the one below obviously fails while object is created in different block every time):

```
def get_session(db_name, verbose, test):
"""Returns current DB session from SQLAlchemy pool.

>>> get_session('Mmusc20090126', False, True)
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0xfb5ff0>

"""
if test:
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=verbose)
    log_load.debug('DB in RAM.')
else:
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + 'DB/' + db_name + '.db', echo=verbose)
    log_load.debug('DB stored in file: %s' % 'DB/' + db_name + '.db')

# Create TABLES: Structures, Interactions, Interactors, PDB_UniProt, UniProtSeq
meta.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

return session
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want to use ellipsis, like this:

```
>>> get_session('Mmusc20090126', False, True) #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x...>
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the update of your answer, I was digging online for where I should put this #doctest: +ELLIPSIS thingy (I thought that using nose makes it different from unitest) ;)